# Some IE9 users unable to log in with htpasswd with some credentials

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer-9, .htpasswd

### **Some** IE9 users unable to log in to a folder which is htpasswd protected

I have normal htaccess/htpasswd protected folders. Some IE9 users are finding that one set of credentials (user/pass) is not working, while other sets of credentials are fine.

- Only affecting IE9, and ?IE8. Firefox, Chrome etc all fine with the credentials that don't work in IE.
- Of 7 IE9 users, 4 can't log in with these credentials, 3 can.
- The username and password are both composed only of letters and numbers (12 and 7).
- The same version number for IE9 is present across the can/can't group.
- Caching is excluded as cause as 6 of the test group were first-time users.
- Directly accessing the file instead of the folder does not help.
- .htpasswd format has been tried as crypt and MD5, without difference.
- The page in question is set to no-cache with an expiry time in the past.
- The same user that cannot log in to folder A, can log in to folder B (with different credentials).
- The same user that cannot log in with credentials A can log in with credentials B (both MD5).
- The position of that set of credentials in the .htpasswd file seems to make no difference.
- The failing credentials also fail (for same IE9 user) on a different folder.

I am completely stumped. The only thing I can come up with is that somehow the combination of letters/numbers in the non-working credentials is causing the ... the what? And why only in IE9 (and possibly IE8)?

I really need to find a cause as opposed to just a solution (change these specific credentials), as we have dozens of combinations of user/password for various folders on this site, any of which could be affected by this problem.

---

**EDIT**: also checked the following (as IE8/win7 had bugs relating to these)

- Checking 'remember password' makes no difference
- Pasting vs typing the password makes no difference

I'm currently investigating whether case sensitivity, inclusion of numbers, or the actual MD5 hash produced (inclusion of special chars etc) makes any difference.

Comment: That sounds knarly. Is there any difference between how the can/can't groups are connecting to the network? WiFi vs. wired, behind a proxy or a firewall, different networks, from work vs. from home? Are you able to inspect the auth headers, either in the server response asking for auth, or the resulting browser request containing the creds? Maybe they're being malformed under certain conditions?

Comment: I think you are correct - the headers are malformed. However, in trying to capture the malformed headers to confirm this, we switched on developer tools and from that moment on, the headers were sent correctly. And now the user can access all the folders that previously didn't work. Gotta love IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Using curl and charles we were able to establish that all other browsers are sending:

Authorization: Basic [Big long sequence followed by]=

and IE9, when failing is sending:

Authorization: Basic [Big long sequence followed by]g

The first one decodes to username:password

the IE9 decodes to username:password[plus a space]

Despite the user clearing spaces from the password input box, it seems that IE9 is sometimes incorrectly appending a space to the password before encoding it.